# UDP Packets IOS 9 LTE Network GCDASYNCUDP

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a basestation (beaglebone running linux) at my home which is connected to multiple cameras. I connect my iPhone iOS9 to the basestation via TCP and the basestation will stream the video of each camera to a specific UDP port.  All is well.

I want to be able to see the cameras when I am not connected to the local network.  When my phone is connected to LTE, I have the iPhone connecting to the public address of my router via TCP and with port forwarding, all data is forwarded to the basestation.  I am connecting and talking just like it was on the local network with the TCP client.  All is well.

The problem is when the video is streamed via UDP on a specific port, no different than when on the local network, the basestation has no problem sending the packets, but the iPhone is not receiving anything.  I am using GCDASYNCUDPSOCKET and my cellular carrier is Verizon.

I am wondering if this issue is due to Verizon blocking UDP packets?  Or possibly there needs to be something else done other than just binding the iPhone UDP socket to a specific port and calling the beginreceiving function.  I feel if it works on the local network, it should work on the cellular network.

I have also tried to ping the address of my cellphone from my computer which does not work.  I am guessing the reason is because the iPhone has blocked this.  It should be no different than pinging the address of google or anything else.

Please give me some insight on the possible issues or work arounds.  I don't think I need to port forward the UDP since it is only outgoing and my Netgear router does not limit any outbound traffic (from the router to the iPhone).  I was doing all this TCP before trying to send the video via UDP.  It is much slower waiting to receive acks for 5 cameras streaming live video.  And when it doesn't receive a packet it backs up the buffer and causes more issues.  Also I had an issue with the TCP packets combining together so then I had to implement some kind of custom ack which made the delay worse, or add an end of message, but then it slows down on parsing and since I don't know exactly what data is coming it made things more difficult.

UDP is the way to go, just cannot receive the packets at this time.  My understanding is a lot of games use UDP and they work on LTE network, so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.  Is there special UDP ports that only work with Verizon?

Comment: How are you attempting to receive the UDP packets? The apple docs say that address based routing does not automatically include the cellular network. So if you are using raw addresses with BSD sockets, you may be in a pinch.